# Different results depending on when I create a GIN index before or after inserting data

Tags: postgresql

I an trying to build a very simple text array `GIN` with `_text_ops`.  I know all about `ts_vectors` - I just want to do this with text arrays as a curiosity and I am seeing a strange behavior in PostgreSQL 9.6.  Here is my sequence of commands:

```
drop table docs cascade;
drop index gin1;
CREATE TABLE docs (id SERIAL, doc TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id));
-- create index gin1 on docs using gin(string_to_array(doc, ' ')  _text_ops);  -- before
INSERT INTO docs (doc) VALUES
('This is SQL and Python and other fun teaching stuff'),
('More people should learn SQL from us'),
('We also teach Python and also SQL');
SELECT * FROM docs;
create index gin1 on docs using gin(string_to_array(doc, ' ')  _text_ops);  -- after
explain select doc from docs where '{SQL}' <@ string_to_array(doc, ' ');
```

If I create the `gin1` index before the inserts the `explain` works as expected:

```
pg4e=> explain select doc FROM docs WHERE '{SQL}' <@ string_to_array(doc, ' ');
 Bitmap Heap Scan on docs  (cost=12.05..21.53 rows=6 width=32)
   Recheck Cond: ('{SQL}'::text[] <@ string_to_array(doc, ' '::text))
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gin1  (cost=0.00..12.05 rows=6 width=0)
         Index Cond: ('{SQL}'::text[] <@ string_to_array(doc, ' '::text))
```

If I create the `gin` index after the inserts, it never seems to use the index.

```
pg4e=> explain select doc from docs where '{SQL}' <@ string_to_array(doc, ' ');
 Seq Scan on docs  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=32)
   Filter: ('{SQL}'::text[] <@ string_to_array(doc, ' '::text))
```

I wondered if it is because I need to wait a while for the index to be fully populated (even with four rows) - but waiting several minutes and doing the `explain` still gives me a sequential table scan.

Then just for fun I insert 10000 more records

```
INSERT INTO docs (doc) SELECT 'Neon ' || generate_series(10000,20000);
```

The `explain` shows a Seq Scan for about 10 seconds and then after 10 seconds if I do another `explain` it shows a Bitmap Heap Scan.  So clearly some of the index updating took a few moments - that makes sense.  But in the first situation where I insert four rows and then create the index - no matter how long I wait `explain` never uses the index.

I have a workaround (make the index before doing the inserts) - I am mostly just curious if there is some mechanism like a "flush index" or that I missed - or some other mechanism is at work.

Comment: For a table with just four rows, an index will never be used

Comment: If you do a VACUUM ANALYZE, then neither one will use the index, because an index on a table with 4 rows is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The explain shows a Seq Scan for about 10 seconds and then after 10
>   seconds if I do another explain it shows a Bitmap Heap Scan. So
>   clearly some of the index updating took a few moments - that makes
>   sense. But in the first situation where I insert four rows and then
>   create the index - no matter how long I wait explain never uses the
>   index.

When you insert 10,000 rows to a 4 row table, you exceed the level of activity determined by autovacuum_analyze_threshold and autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor.  So the next time the autovacuum launcher visits your database, it will execute an ANALYZE of the table, and with new data from that ANALYZE on a largish table it decides the index scan will be useful.  But if you just insert 4 rows, that will not trigger an auto analyze (the default value of autovacuum_analyze_threshold is 50).  And if it did, the result of the ANALYZE would be that the table is so small that the index is not useful, so the plan would not change anyway.

> I have a workaround (make the index before doing the inserts)

To have a workaround, you need to have a problem.  You don't seem to have a genuine problem here (that lasts longer than autovacuum_naptime, anyway), so there is nothing to work around.

Comment: Thanks - this is so helpful.